# User cancel load after 'beforeunload'

Tags: javascript

I couldn't find the answer here on Stack Overflow.

I have a website where on page load I have an event listener waiting to pick up 'beforeunload':

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function () {
    console.log("beforeunload");
});
```

But I would like to make an eventlistener to get feedback if the loading event has been cancelled. For example, if you click on another page within a website and press `esc` on your keyboard the page will stop loading. How would I be able to catch that event? I have already tried to catch something with 'unload' and 'load' without any positive results.

Comment: Are you saying you want to catch the "stop-loading" event on the page being left, not on the page being loaded?

Comment: @Bergi Not on it being left but on the loading cancelled, or that must be the same thing?